# How can I route components in another component without changing url?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, bootstrap-4

Let's assume that I have Angular 5 project with routings. For instance `/home, /landing-page, etc`. Moreover, let's assume that in my landing page with url - `localhost:4200`. I want to create login panel. I have two fields - `username` and `password`, one button `sign in` and two other buttons `forgot password?` and `Don't have an account?`. My problem is that when user will click `Forgot password?` or `Don't have an account?` he will not be routed to another page with url like `localhost:4200/sign-up` but he will stay at the same page with url `localhost:4200` and fields `username, password, sign in, forgot password?` and `Don't have an account?` will disappear and in their place will be displayed fields associated with registration. I am not sure whether you know what I mean. The good example what I wanna to achieve is https://www.instagram.com. No matter whether you click Sign up or Log in you are still on the same url and only one component changes. Do you know how can I achieve this? I am not sure whether I should use routes or maybe another way is more optimal to do this? Thanks in advance.

My code looks in this way. I added only the most important code from selected files.

index.html:

```
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="removeFooter()"></app-footer>
```

At the moment my `home.component` looks in this way:

home.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="isSignIn()">
  <app-sign-in></app-sign-in>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isSignUp()">
  <app-sign-up></app-sign-up>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isForgotPassword()">
  <app-forgot-password></app-forgot-password>
</div>
```

home.component.ts:

```
    constructor() {
      this.signin = true;
      this.signup = false;
      this.forgot = false;
    }

  isSignUp() {
    if (this.signup === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  isSignIn() {
    if (this.signin === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  isForgotPassword() {
    if (this.forgot === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

sign-in.component.html:

```
<div class="content-center">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="title-brand">

      <div align="center">

        <input style="background-color: black; border-color: white; color:white; width: 270px" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="USERNAME">

        <br>

        <input style="background-color: black; border-color: white; color:white; width: 270px" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="PASSWORD">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <br>
            <button style="background-color: black; border-color: white; color:white; width: 270px" type="button"  class="btn btn-danger">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br>

        <h6  style = "color: white" [routerLink]="['/main']" skipLocationChange class=pointer>Forgot Password?</h6>
        <h6 style="color: white" [routerLink]="['/sign-up']" class=pointer>Don't have an account?</h6>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I added source code of sign-in.component.html to the question. Can you show me how I can switch the component sign-in.component.html after clicking Forgot Password? or Do not have an account? to the component forgot.component.html or `sign-up.component.html`

Comment: You could use a flag to switch between displayed components? when the user clicks the button, change the flag and use `*ngIf` to only display the component/fields you want.

Comment: @SimplyGed Can you show me example?

Comment: See e.g. https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange

Answer (score 1):

Use `skipLocationChange` from the route `NavigationExtras`. E.g.

```
<h6  style = "color: white" [routerLink]="['/main']" skipLocationChange>Forgot Password?</h6>
<h6 style="color: white" [routerLink]="['/sign-up']" skipLocationChange>Don't have an account?</h6>
```

Comment: It helps not to change url after routing but how can I change components in the way described in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a boolean and buttons to allow you to switch between different components on a single page:

[stackblitz example](https://angular-w5daz8.stackblitz.io)

This example could be improved but I hope it shows you how to easily swap the visible component.

You can view the code at [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5daz8)

**EDIT**

You need to remove the responsibility of what component to show to a container component (i.e. a parent component). In the updated [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5daz8) I've made the `HomeComponent` responsible for showing the correct component. This means the `SignUp/SignIn/ForgotPassword` components have no responsibility for switching between each other - that is the job for the `HomeComponent` (or whichever component you want to use for that job).

Hope that helps

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template:
  `<div *ngIf="signin">
      <app-sign-in></app-sign-in>
      <button (click)="showSignUp()">Sign up</button>
      <button (click)="showForgot()">Forgot password</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="signup">
      <app-sign-up></app-sign-up>
      <button (click)="showSignIn()">Sign in</button>
      <button (click)="showForgot()">Forgot password</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="forgot">
      <app-forgot-password></app-forgot-password>
      <button (click)="showSignUp()">Sign up</button>
      <button (click)="showSignIn()">Sign in</button>
    </div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HomeComponent {
  public signup: boolean = true;
  public signin: boolean = false;
  public forgot: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  public showSignIn() {
    this.signin = true;
    this.signup = this.forgot = false;
  }

  public showSignUp() {
    this.signup = true;
    this.signin = this.forgot = false;
  }

  public showForgot() {
    this.forgot = true;
    this.signin = this.signup = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I have separated components so I would need to have global variables visible for all three components. How can I solve this?

Comment: The variable is only public from the `HomeComponent` so it's not global. And you can simplify your methods by just returning the variable e.g. `return this.isSignin;` And you are still missing a button and method that changes the variables to show the correct component.

Comment: I added source code of `sign-in.component.html` to the question. Can you show me how I can switch the component `sign-in.component.html` after clicking `Forgot Password?` or `Do not have an account?` to the component `forgot.component.html` or` sign-up.component.html`